# How can I change the code to make it such that the html tags do not appear

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.mediacorp.sg/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/ayden-sng-12357686'

artiste_name = 'celeb-name'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

txt = soup.find_all('h1', attrs={'class':artiste_name})

print(txt)
```

with the above code, i get the output:

```
[<*h1 class="celeb-name">Ayden Sng</h1*>] #asterisks added to show h1 tags
```

What do i need to change in my code or how can i make it such that i only get 'Ayden Sng' as my output?

Comment: It's likely somewhat better (long-term) if you use Beautiful Soup's `html5lib` parser as opposed to `lxml`.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over each entry of the `txt` list and extract its `txt` property:

```
txt = [element.text for element in txt] # ['Ayden Sng']
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://replit.com/@esqew/BaggyJealousDaemon#main.py)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests

url = 'https://www.mediacorp.sg/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/ayden-sng-12357686'

artiste_name = 'celeb-name'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

txt = soup.find_all('h1', attrs={'class':artiste_name})

print(txt[0].text)
```

if there are more than one reuslt you can use this code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests

url = 'https://www.mediacorp.sg/en/your-mediacorp/our-artistes/tca/male-artistes/ayden-sng-12357686'

artiste_name = 'celeb-name'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

txt = soup.find_all('h1', attrs={'class':artiste_name})
for i in txt:
  print(i.text)
```